# NotificationCompat.Builder setSound() not working for .mp3 resource and product flavours

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-resources, android-productflavors

This is what I'm doing and it still plays the default sound, on emulator and device:

```
Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sleep_tone);
...
mNotificationBuilder.setSound(sound);
```

It did work previously, before I added product flavours. I have 2 product flavours with package name suffixes .free and .pro. Replacing `context.getPackageName()` with  `com.mycompany.myapp.free` or `.pro` doesn't work, and no suffix at all doesn't work. 
The mp3 file is stored under main/res/raw. It doesn't matter if I store it in pro/res/raw it still doesn't work. How do I access it?

Comment: Did you find a way ?

Comment: No sorry not yet

Comment: I converted my Audio file to Wav and it worked

Comment: Check if you have ```mNotificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);``` value set